# Android Skobbler 2.5.1, calculateRouteWithPoints cause a crash

Tags: android, android-studio, skmaps

I have updated Android Skobbler to 2.5.1, now calculateRouteWithPoints cause a crash :

```
11-13 17:38:59.277 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila E/SKRouteManager: GPX track navigation is available for commercial use with a enterprise license
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jmethodID was NULL
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     in call to CallDoubleMethodV
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     from void com.skobbler.ngx.routing.SKRouteManager.createroutefromgpspoints(com.skobbler.ngx.positioner.SKPosition[], int, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x734472a0 self=0xb4d36500
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | sysTid=8669 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f1cb34
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | state=R schedstat=( 3080950577 2781792242 9518 ) utm=247 stm=61 core=1 HZ=100
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | stack=0xbe689000-0xbe68b000 stackSize=8MB
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #00 pc 00370aa9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+160)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #01 pc 003503b7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+150)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #02 pc 0025a6fd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+740)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #03 pc 0025add5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, std::__va_list)+64)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #04 pc 000fd1d1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+32)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #05 pc 00102f01  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::Check(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, bool, char const*, art::JniValueType*) (.constprop.95)+8172)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #06 pc 00110b73  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallMethodV(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+534)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #07 pc 00112021  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallDoubleMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+36)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #08 pc 000fa67b  /data/app/fr.apila.apila-2/lib/arm/libngnative.so (_JNIEnv::CallDoubleMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+22)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #09 pc 000e9df1  /data/app/fr.apila.apila-2/lib/arm/libngnative.so (Java_com_skobbler_ngx_routing_SKRouteManager_createroutefromgpspoints+144)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #10 pc 00d73d9f  /data/app/fr.apila.apila-2/oat/arm/base.odex (void com.skobbler.ngx.routing.SKRouteManager.createroutefromgpspoints(com.skobbler.ngx.positioner.SKPosition[], int, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean)+138)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #11 pc 00d78827  /data/app/fr.apila.apila-2/oat/arm/base.odex (void com.skobbler.ngx.routing.SKRouteManager.calculateRouteWithPoints(java.util.List, com.skobbler.ngx.routing.SKRouteSettings)+674)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #12 pc 00e1861d  /data/app/fr.apila.apila-2/oat/arm/base.odex (void fr.apila.apila.activity.MapActivity.launchNavigationWay(java.lang.String, boolean)+1960)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #13 pc 00e13923  /data/app/fr.apila.apila-2/oat/arm/base.odex (void fr.apila.apila.activity.MapActivity.sendBroadcastParkCalculated()+1398)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #14 pc 00e12a9f  /data/app/fr.apila.apila-2/oat/arm/base.odex (void fr.apila.apila.activity.MapActivity.calculateParkingDistanceAndTime()+1034)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #15 pc 00e1e45b  /data/app/fr.apila.apila-2/oat/arm/base.odex (void fr.apila.apila.activity.MapActivity.onRouteCalculationCompleted(com.skobbler.ngx.routing.SKRouteInfo)+2670)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #16 pc 010341d7  /data/app/fr.apila.apila-2/oat/arm/base.odex (void com.skobbler.ngx.routing.SKRouteManager$1.run()+210)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #17 pc 007d9037  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (???)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.skobbler.ngx.routing.SKRouteManager.createroutefromgpspoints(Native method)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.skobbler.ngx.routing.SKRouteManager.calculateRouteWithPoints(SourceFile:327)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at fr.apila.apila.activity.MapActivity.launchNavigationWay(MapActivity.java:1371)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at fr.apila.apila.activity.MapActivity.sendBroadcastParkCalculated(MapActivity.java:567)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at fr.apila.apila.activity.MapActivity.calculateParkingDistanceAndTime(MapActivity.java:1295)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at fr.apila.apila.activity.MapActivity.onRouteCalculationCompleted(MapActivity.java:1534)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.skobbler.ngx.routing.SKRouteManager$1.run(SourceFile:819)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-13 17:38:59.360 8669-8669/fr.apila.apila A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]
```

My code doesn't change from 2.5.0, there it is :

```
SKRouteSettings route = new SKRouteSettings();

route.setNoOfRoutes(1);
route.setRouteMode(SKRouteSettings.SKRouteMode.CAR_SHORTEST);
route.setRouteExposed(true);
SKRouteManager.getInstance().setRouteListener(this);
SKRouteManager.getInstance().calculateRouteWithPoints(coordinatesListResult, route);
```

And there is the variable coordinatesListResult:

```
 [SKPosition [latitude=48.852404348, longitude=2.37195116, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8524722, longitude=2.3717558, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8527173, longitude=2.3712392, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8529545, longitude=2.3708284, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8531988, longitude=2.3704617, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8533113, longitude=2.3703109, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8533434, longitude=2.3703526, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8534504, longitude=2.3704626, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8540171, longitude=2.3710404, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8542429, longitude=2.3712707, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8543359, longitude=2.3714113, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.854374, longitude=2.3715182, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8548014, longitude=2.3727158, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8549353, longitude=2.3730649, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8551004, longitude=2.3734949, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.855232, longitude=2.3737648, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8553718, longitude=2.3740514, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8555259, longitude=2.3744148, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8558703, longitude=2.3741016, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8564505, longitude=2.3734747, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8556876, longitude=2.3716429, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8554605, longitude=2.3706467, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.855449, longitude=2.3704872, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8563672, longitude=2.370919, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8570516, longitude=2.3712172, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8568963, longitude=2.3722219, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0], SKPosition [latitude=48.8571876, longitude=2.3728056, heading=0.0, horizontalAccuracy=0.0, verticalAccuracy=0.0, speed=0.0, altitude=0.0]]
```

Any idea ? I have to downgrade to 2.5.0 while I'm waiting your response.

Answer (score 1):

With the initial release of 2.5.1 SDK when using a large number of points caused an SIGSEGV error.

The following resources need be used to fix the issue: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1z2529hvddcbxp5/calculateRouteFromPointsIssue_Public%20SDK_2.5.1_libs.zip?dl=0

Comment: Hi @SylviA, I recently ran across this issue as well but I currently use the custom 2.5.1 build with traffic enabled as well. Is there an updated version of the SDK that contains both the fix for the large number of points issue along with support for traffic enabled routing? Thank you for any help!

Comment: @Keith, yes we can send it to you. please reach out to us at dev@telenav.com